# Scripts no longer work after moving to _layout (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, layout

All scripts worked fine when I had just a view.
And when I tried to split it into layout and partial view - scripts no longer worked.
Please answer the questions:
1) where links should be placed? In a view or in _layout?
If in layout, so should I use
    @Scripts.Render
or just

2) Where scripts should be placed? In a view or in _layout?
Or can I do like this: place scripts in view in 
    @section Scripts{ }
and then in layout use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can add scripts in your master _layout page where all the html is created and all views should use this _layout.

Your _layout page should look like as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />       
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)     
    </head>
    <body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```